# Installing Ubuntu Onto a Computer That Doesn't Have An Operating System

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-to-install-ubuntu)

I'm getting a computer later on today, one without an operating system. I can't afford an operating system, so I'm thinking of going with the free Ubuntu instead of pirating one. How would I go about doing this? Can anyone link me to a tutorial for this? Will it work the same as getting it onto a computer with an operating system?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu - the link above has the links that will help you get going including a full tutorial and where to download.  Feel free to ask any questions after you have installed - or if you have any issues during the install.

Comment: Basically, burn the image to a CD or DVD or USB card and boot the system using it as a boot device.  See the more complete how-to's for more info.

Comment: Also, if you have any issues, ask more questions here!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to install ubuntu beside windows or another OS you should be fine to install ubuntu as the only OS. The only challenge I can imagine could be, that the HD is not formatted at all. To solve this challenge, boot into the live session, either from usb stick or cd, and use gparted to format the drive, either fat 32 or ext 4, after this install ubuntu and hopefully if the hardware is supported everything should work fine

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu unstaller needs the hard drive to be pre-formatted as fat32... that would be funny actually. So no additional challenges - boot from a CD or USB stick and proceed.